# AVQueuePlayer play streaming after become active iPa on iPad, any suggestion?

Tags: ios, ipad, audio

We use HysteriaPlayer and it use AVQueuePlayer to play files, the steps are:

1. Play streaming
2. Pause streaming
3. Lock iPad
4. Unlock iPad
5. The audio streaming start to play

AVQueuePlayer play audio after become active iPa on iPad, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could related to AVAudioSession interruption, and HysteriaPlayer would show logs for debugging on this issue.

See your logs, if you can't see logs printed by HysteriaPlayer then you gotta check HysteriaPlayer's disableLogs property.